# Image overlapping the other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to avoid absolute positioning if it's possible...
I have the following html code:

```
<section class="mainfeatures" id="features">
    <!-- Container -->
    <div class="container small-width">
        <div class="one_half text-align-center">
            <div  id="standleft">       
                <img src="http://www.fusionkatz.com/Assets/Jerome%201.jpg" alt="" >
            </div>
            <div  id="standright">
                <img src="http://www.koreanfilm.org/tom/wp-content/uploads/dancing-cat2.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="one_half last">
            <div class="middle_part2">
                <h2>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</h2>
                <p >lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--/Container -->
</section>
```

and the css for it:

```
.one_half {
    width: 48%;
}

.one_half {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 4%;
    position: relative;
}

.last {
    margin-right: 0px!important;
}

.text-align-center {
    text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .container.small-width {
        width: 600px;
    }
    .one_half {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-right: 0%;
    }
    .one_half {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

So far, as you can see in my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zgobmdL2/ on both (normal and media) screens the two images are one above the other. I want an image to actually **overlap** the other, like here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/97q5X.png and in case of mobile browsing, like here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHZvR.png

I tried playing around with `position: absolute`, but I know it shouldn't be used with bootstrap (I'm not totally sure...). Is there any way of fixing my layout?
Thanks!

Comment: I do not see anything wrong to use `position: absolute;`

Comment: You don't want one image above the other but you want one image on top of each other? Please explain.

Comment: @Rob I want to use sth like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zgobmdL2/2/ when one image is on top of the other, but it uses `absolute` positioning and I thought there might be a way of avoiding it with bootstrap... Now with current solution when I shrink the page the text covers the photos and I would like them to appear below the text..

Comment: i don't see any bootstrap grid in your css

Comment: @Syahrul is it possible to solve my problem with bootstrap grid? can you give me an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using [bootstrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

**DEMO** : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zgobmdL2/3/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-sm-6" id="standleft">       
        <img src="http://www.fusionkatz.com/Assets/Jerome%201.jpg" alt="" >
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" id="standright">
        <img src="http://www.koreanfilm.org/tom/wp-content/uploads/dancing-cat2.jpg" alt="">
      </div>      
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</h2>
      <p >lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```